# How to get `mtext()` with partial bold text?

Tags: r

I would like to add a text to my plot so that one letter, **a**, appears bold. I started with the following, but the result is not what I need:

```
plot(1:5,axes=F)
mtext(c(only a should be bold),1:1,font=2)
```

What should I do to make only a bold?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Complex text editing can be done with `expression`. See `?plotmath` for a list of commands.

```
mtext(expression(paste("only ", bold("a"), " should be bold")), 1, 1)
```

[image]